# Passing state into an Ajax call ReactJS and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I have a ProductItem component that when the user clicks 'Add to Basket' performs an AJAX post call to create a basket item.

However I can't seem to pass state into the Ajax call at the moment and so it's missing the dynamic data it needs.

The component looks like this and state is setting correctly on the Product Item component when I check in react developer tools on chrome.

```
class ProductItem extends React.Component{

constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = { 
        name: '',
        price: 0,
        code: '',
        id: ''
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState( {
        name: this.props.data.name,
        price: this.props.data.price,
        code: this.props.data.code,
        id: this.props.data.id
    })
}

addtoBasket(props) {
    console.log(props.name) /* RETURNS UNDEFINED */
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/items",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            item: {
                name: 'Trousers',
                price: 52.00,
                code: 'T01'
            }
        },
        success: function() {

            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
}

render(){
    let productName = this.props.data.name
    let productPrice = this.props.data.price
    let productCode = this.props.data.code
    let productImg = this.props.data.image_url

    return (
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 product">
            <img src={productImg}/>
            <h3 className="text-center">{productName}</h3>
            <h5 className="text-center">£{productPrice}</h5>
            <div className="text-center">
                <button onClick={this.addtoBasket.bind(this.props)} className="btn btn-primary">Add to Basket</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

How can I fix this and correctly pass state or props to the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your button to below code

```
<button onClick={this.addtoBasket.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Add to Basket</button>
```

And then you will be able to get the context of this.

Or other way

```
 <button onClick={this.addtoBasket.bind(this , this.props)} className="btn btn-primary">Add to Basket</button>
```

And in addtoBasket method

```
addtoBasket(props){
  console.log("Prrops" , props)
}
```

That should work :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `this.addtoBasket.bind(this.props)` call - the `bind` method's argument will become `this` in the bound function. So called like this it binds `props` to be `this`, not the class.

You probably wanted to do `this.addtoBasket.bind(this)` instead.

And the `addtoBasket` function's argument will be the `onClick` event, not the props.